# Auth::user()->id wont work Laravel 5.2 / Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have 2 logins with different controller/model. 
1 - for contender_user
2 - for enterprise_user. 
Although they look totally identical in the file with the enterprise user i cant reach the id of the enterprise_user

1. File with no Error:

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers\contender_user;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   use App\Http\Requests;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use App\Models\contender_user;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


   class contender_userController extends Controller
   {


       public function applications_contender_user_show () {
          return view('contender_user/applications');
       }


       public function home_show () {

          $id = Auth::user()->id;
          $contender_user = new contender_user\contender_userModel();

          $results = $contender_user->get_user_all($id);


           return view('contender_user/home', array
               (
                  'name'    =>  $results[0]->name,
                  'email'  =>  $results[0]->email,
                  'created_at'  =>  $results[0]->created_at
               ));

       }
   }
   ```
2. File with Error:
   Line: $id = Auth::user()->id;
   Error: Trying to get property of non-object

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers\enterprise_user;


   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
   use App\Http\Requests;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use App\Models\enterprise_user;

   class enterprise_userController extends Controller
   {
   public function applications_show () {
       return view('enterprise_user/applications');
   }

   public function home_show () {

       $id = Auth::user()->id;
       $enterprise_user = new enterprise_user\enterprise_userModel();

       $results = $enterprise_user->get_user_all($id);


       return view('enterprise_user/home', array
           (
               'name'    =>  $results[0]->name,
               'email'  =>  $results[0]->email,
               'created_at'  =>  $results[0]->created_at
           )
       );

   }
   ```

When i Copy the working file it still comes to the error message :(

pls help

Comment: are you using any guard?

Comment: Check user session exist or not(Auth::check()) before using Auth::user()

Comment: `$id = Auth::id();` will do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

For [Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) you can get authenticated user as below:

```
Auth::guard('user')->user()->id //guard can be user,admin etc depend on your settings
```

Comment: php storm says use Method "guard" not found altough i have the line : use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function home_show () {
   if($id){
     $enterprise_user = new enterprise_user\enterprise_userModel();

    $results = $enterprise_user->get_user_all($id);


    return view('enterprise_user/home', array
        (
            'name'    =>  $results[0]->name,
            'email'  =>  $results[0]->email,
            'created_at'  =>  $results[0]->created_at
        )
    );
}
else{
    ///what ever you want to do
}

}
```